# Checking the number of files in a specific folder

Tags: linux, files, find, cd-command

I have 100 folders (called "Folder_1", "Folder_2", "Folder_3", ...) containing several files. From a loop over each folder, I would like to run commands (*i.e.*, display the folder name) depending on conditions (*i.e.*, number of files in the folder is not equal to 20133). Here is my code:

```
for f in *Folder*/; do cd "$f"; if ["$(find . -type f | wc -l)" -ne 20133]; then echo "$f" && cd ..; fi; done
```

However, I have these error messages:

```
-bash: cd: Folder_1/: No such file or directory
-bash: [20133: command not found
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the fact that you always enter the current directory (`cd "$f"`) but only go back up one directory if you score a hit (`then echo "$f" && cd ..`).

This is what I did to create a test environment and write a working example:

```
johan@iMac:~$ mkdir -p example/Folder_{1..20}
johan@iMac:~$ touch example/Folder_{1..20}/file_{1..10}
johan@iMac:~$ touch example/Folder_{18..20}/file_{11..15}
johan@iMac:~$ cd example
johan@iMac:~/example$ for f in Folder_*; do test "$(find "$f" -type f | wc -l)" -eq 15 && echo "$f"; done
Folder_18
Folder_19
Folder_20
johan@iMac:~/example$ cd ..
johan@iMac:~$ rm -rf example/
```

Note that I used the built in `test` instead of the [ ... ] syntax to improve readability. Fun fact, the `[` character is just a program, and is the same as the `test` program. That is the reason it needs spaces around its arguments :)

Here check this out (On my iMac)

```
johan@iMac:~$ md5 /bin/test
MD5 (/bin/test) = 2c4b51263409bd39f1ea0fa4f925130a
johan@iMac:~$ md5 /bin/[
MD5 (/bin/[) = 2c4b51263409bd39f1ea0fa4f925130a
```